# access global variable as static class variable

Tags: php

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class SQLMapper{
    static find_user_by_id($id){
        //sql logic here, using the $_DATABASE global to make a connection
    }
}
```

I could simply call:

```
global $_DATABASE;
```

at the top of my function, but I don't want to do that for ALL of my static methods.  Is there a way to get a static variable inside my class to reference the global $_DATABASE array?

EDIT:  I can't assign it in the constructor, since this is all static, and the constructor is never called.

Comment: Why does it all have to be static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the super-global array `$_GLOBALS` to access your `$_DATABASE` variable. For example:

```
query( $GLOBALS['_DATABASE'], 'some query' );
```

Alternatively, write a static function that returns the contents of that variable:

```
class SQLMapper
{
    static function getDatabase()
    {
        global $_DATABASE;
        return $_DATABASE;
    }

    static function find_user_by_id($id)
    {
        query( self::getDatabase(), 'some query' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> If it hurts, its likely that you're
>   doing it wrong.

First off, without seeing more of your code its impossible to provide a more concrete solution, but I would strongly recommend that you consider rearranging your class structure so that your static functions (it sounds like you've got a long list of them to implement) become non-static.

In essence, you should consider accessing an instantiated instance of SQLMapper and then calling the appropriate method from the instance. Using this paradigm, you could just instantiate a class level property for $_DATABASE which can then be freely referenced by all methods in the class.

For example:

```
class SQLMapper {

    private $_db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        global $_DATABASE;

        $this->_db = $_DATABASE;
    }

    public function find_user_by_id($id) {

        $sql = "Select * from User WHERE Id = ?";

        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare($sql, $id);

        return $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

With that said, using globals is generally a sign of poor code quality so I would also suggest that you consider taking a more object-oriented approach to your current design and look for tried and true methods for eliminating globals from your application altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure I understand what you mean, sorry, but can you try using the [static keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)?

Comment: This would make a better comment than answer.